# Doctype not working as it should be

Tags: css, html, doctype

I have a problem with doctype,it seems when I add it,in my page,the css doesnt work.But when i remove doctype,everything works fine.what could be the reason

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">this is my header
    </div>
    <div id="center_content">
        <div id="left">
        </div><div id="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">this is my footer
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
body
{

margin:0px;
padding:0px;

}
#wrapper
{
height:100%;
width:100%
}
#header
{
width:100%;
height:20%;
background-color:red;
}
#center_content
{
min-height:79%;
height:auto;
background-color:pink;
overflow:auto;

}
#footer
{
height:5%;
background-color:blue;  
}
#left
{
float:left;
min-height:79%;
height:auto;
width:20%;
background-color:brown;
}
#right
{
float:right;
min-height:79%;
height:auto;
width:79%;
background-color:yellow;

}
```

Comment: Live link ? Check your console for errors, also since you are using the html5 doctype you don't need to set a type for the css link

Comment: I think you have a different definition of "should" from the standard.

Comment: Also use hex/rgb/rgba instead of red,pink...

Comment: Height in percentage for an element is only _supposed_ to work if the height for the parent element is explicitly set.

Comment: There's a specific reason why percentage heights work without a DOCTYPE. See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276

Answer (score 1):

Your doctype is not the issue. You just need to understand when using % percentage you should also declare percentage width and height to the parent/ancestor which is `<html>` and `<body`>.

I had modified your css. try this.

```
html, body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color:red;
}
#center_content {
    height:79%;
    background-color:pink;
    overflow:auto;
}
#footer {
    height:5%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
    background-color:brown;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    height:100%;
    width:79%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

So, when you removed the doctype it enters in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) which is why it renders fine without the doctype.